# Content Editor Web Part for Lists

Tags: content-editor-web-part

I try to apply some styles to the list. I added CEWP into the page and edited the source. 
It is CEWP's source:

```
<style type="text/css">
body{background-color:white;}
</style>
```

It doesn't work. Why doesn't it work? I'm using SP 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are there is another style that is overwriting your style that is either more specific, or loaded after yours.

Try using Firefox with the Firebug add-on or the Chrome Developer tools in Google Chrome to select the element and see what styles are being applied and from where.

Or, if you're just trying to change the background color for a list, it wouldn't be the body tag that you'd be styling. It's much more specific than that. Like I said above, your best bet is to open the page and use the developer tools to find out the class you should be targeting.

Comment: the id of the div which includes the list web part is"WebPartWPQ2 . I found this web site and did what he says and nothing worked. [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/493775/Apply-CSS-styles-to-SharePoint-Web-parts) '<style type="text/css">#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 .ms-WPHeader{background-color:white;}</style>'

Comment: Ok I did it. Thank you. <style type="text/css">#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2{background-color:white;}</style>

Comment: Follow the instructions here and make sure you don't mix up zeros and O's. 
http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2009/01/stylize-individual-web-parts-with-cewp.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you wrapped your css in a style tag like:

```
<style type="text/css">
body
{
...
}
</style>
```

?

Comment: Yes, I did but nothing works

Comment: Have you tried styling another element on the page? Or tried using the !important attribute on the style rule?

It is possible that your rule is overruled by standard corev4.css or any other css file

Comment: No. On the page there is just one list and the content editor wp is on the top of it. So it has to style only that list. I didn't use !important.

Comment: Well no mather if the list is the only thing on the page, sharepoint will still use all rules from corev4.css as a base style.

Sometimes the corev4 is harder to override than you wish. But trying to style other elements on the page could help you see if your css is loaded at all (like making some text change color)

Comment: I put a div with class called "CustomPart" and changed "body" into ".CustomPart",nothing happened.